# Postfix unable to send mail to Gmail

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, gmail

I am learning how to host a postfix server (Beginner), i have been able to receive email from gmail, but i am trying to send to Gmail, this is my "tail /var/log/mail.log"

```
Dec 15 14:24:49 thepocketmerlin postfix/smtp[25424]: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[172.253.112.27]:25: Connection timed out
Dec 15 14:24:49 thepocketmerlin postfix/smtp[25424]: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2607:f8b0:4024:c00::1a]:25: Network is unreachable
Dec 15 14:24:49 thepocketmerlin postfix/smtp[25424]: connect to alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2607:f8b0:4002:c08::1a]:25: Network is unreachable
Dec 15 14:25:19 thepocketmerlin postfix/smtp[25424]: connect to alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[64.233.177.26]:25: Connection timed out
Dec 15 14:25:49 thepocketmerlin postfix/smtp[25424]: connect to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[173.194.68.27]:25: Connection timed out
Dec 15 14:25:49 thepocketmerlin postfix/smtp[25424]: 528BB3F132: to=<thepocketmerlin@gmail.com>, relay=none, delay=90, delays=0.03/0.01/90/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to alt2.gmail-smtp in.l.google.com[173.194.68.27]:25: Connection timed out)
```

mailq (result)

```
528BB3F132      372 Tue Dec 15 14:24:19  sheller@thepocketmerlin.tk
(connect to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[173.194.68.27]:25: Connection timed out)
                                         thepocketmerlin@gmail.com
```

Any Ideas?.

Comment: `Connection timed out` suggests you don't have connectivity on SMTP port 25. Probably you are trying to host the server on a connection that doesn't either allow hosting mail servers or blocks SMTP by default. Call your service provider.

Comment: It's my own aws ec2 server and I have opened the ports egress and ingress, I was able to receive email too, but sending to Gmail keeps giving me this problem, could the problem be from reverse dns, because I didn't define it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the comments you say it's an AWS EC2 instance. AWS restricts outbound SMTP by default. The internal firewall rules on your instance doesn't help with that, but  you have to request for a removal.

[How do I remove the restriction on port 25 from my EC2 instance?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-port-25-throttle/)

> **Resolution**
>
> Amazon EC2 restricts outbound traffic on port 25 of all EC2 instances
> by default. You can request the removal of this restriction.
>
> 1. Sign in with your AWS account, and then open the [Request to remove
>    email sending limitations form.](https://aws-portal.amazon.com/gp/aws/html-forms-controller/contactus/ec2-email-limit-rdns-request)

You'd also need...

> A clear and detailed use case for sending email from your EC2 instance.

Learning how to host a mail server isn't necessarily a reason good enough for them. Securing the mail server properly so that you won't end up being used as a relay for spam is hard business.